# Why does toJS() return an empty object when applied on observable object? - MobX

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, jsobject

I am getting an empty object when I do **toJS()** on an observable object. I am assigning the values to the `observableObject` after an API call using **Object.assign()**. Now I am using this `observableObject` in a **computed** method of different store as shown in the code below.

```
class Store {
    @observable observableObject = {};

    Fetch(){
        .....
        APIcall()
        .then((response) => {
            Object.assign(this.observableObject, response.data);
        }).catch(...)
    }
    .....
}

class Store2 {

    @computed get computedValue(){

        // return an non empty {Symbol(mobx administration): ObservableObjectAdministration$$1} object
        console.log(this.rootStore.store1.observableObject);

        // returns True
        console.log(isObservable(this.rootStore.store1.observableObject));

        // return an empty object
        console.log(toJS(this.rootStore.store1.observableObject));

    }
}
```

I have referred to this [issue](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/1117) but couldn't find any help. Find the log of the `observableObject` below. Can anyone explain the unexpected bheviour of `toJS()` in mobx.

EDIT: The target field in the log of proxy mobx observable contains all fields but toJS() conversion yields empty object. Here is the sandbox demo

[image: Edit mobx Object.assign + toJS]

[image: chrome log of the observableObject]

Comment: I wrote an answer, then realised it was version-dependent (irrelevant if you're not using v4 or below). Can you share a complete minimal example that demonstrates the problem? Maybe using https://codesandbox.io or similar.

Comment: Updated the question please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a question of waiting long enough for the API response. In your CodeSandbox, the script exits almost immediately once the API call returns, without waiting for MobX to update anything. If you get lucky it might finish fast enough for you to see some console output, but probably not.

The trick is to wait for the API, then update the store, then read the computed value from it:

```js
import { observable, toJS, runInAction, computed } from "mobx";
import axios from "axios";

class Store {
  @observable observableObject = {};
}

const store = new Store();

class Store2 {
  @computed get computedVar() {
    return toJS(store.observableObject);
  }
}

const store2 = new Store2();
console.log("Object before API call:", store2.computedVar);

axios
  .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
  .then(response => {
    runInAction(() => {
      Object.assign(store.observableObject, response.data);
    });
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Object after API call:", store2.computedVar);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: But why does the target field still shows the correct output in the proxy object?

Comment: When I run your example in the sandbox, all outputs are empty (`{}`). If you're seeing something different, it may be the API request is sometimes coming back quickly enough to update the store in time? Hard to say.